# How would I return a nested array of string in this situation?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to create a function where if you call getDeployedCampaigns, it will output both the address and the string. I want the array of title strings to return with the array of addresses but nested dynamic arrays is not implemented in solidity. Is there a way I can work around this issue so I can return both the arrays of addresses and arrays of string?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract ContractFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;
    string[] public title;
    
    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[], string[]) {
        return (deployedCampaigns, title);
    }
    
    function createCampaign(uint min, string name) public {
        address newCampaign = new Campaign(min, name, msg.sender);
        title.push(name);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }
}

contract Campaign {
    
    address public organizer;
    uint public minContribution;
    string public title;
    
    function Campaign(uint min, string name, address creator) public {
        organizer = creator;
        minContribution = min;
        title = name;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when I make the webpage using react, the campaign address and name will show up for every campaigns created.

[image]

Right now, 0 and 1 is there in place of the title because I couldn't figure out how to get this to work.

```
static async getInitialProps() {
        const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call()

        return { campaigns: campaigns }
}

renderCampaigns() {
        const items = this.props.campaigns.map((address, title) => {
          return {
            header: title,
            description: (
                <Link route={`/campaigns/${address}`}>
                    <a>View Campaign</a>
                </Link>
            ),
            meta: address,
            fluid: true
          };
        });
    
        return <Card.Group items={items} />;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, you need to specify that the error is for attempting to return `string[]` in that function. We're not supposed to guess that!

Comment: Second, you should get rid of the other function posted in this question, because: 1. It has no relevance to the problem at hand. 2. It doesn't even compile, so anyone trying to reproduce your compilation problem receives **a different** compilation problem.

Comment: As to the actual problem, if you're willing to restrict your titles to 32 characters, then you can simply replace `string` with `bytes32` everywhere in the code. Note that in any case, you can simply get rid of that function, and the user will still be able to get each `title` by index, using the implicit getter function `function title(uint256 index) public view returns (string) {return title[index];}`

Comment: I apologize, it's my first time asking a question here and should have specified more. I will edit the question.